# Deleting items from table via Entity model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Now what I'm doing is this:

```
List<myTable> items = (from x in myDb.myTable where x.story == 0 select x).ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    myDb.myTable.DeleteObject(item);
}
myDb.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to do this without the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the LINQ version of ForEach,

```
items.ForEach(x => myDb.myTable.DeleteObject(x));
```

, or append the foreach to the the first query, if you want to make it a bit shorter.